# Python how to detect mouse click on 3D view

Tags: python, scripting

I Want to simulate pressure sensitivity based on mouse speed, but need a way to detect a mouse event and call a method to change the brush strength.

something like this:

```
import bpy

last_mouse_pos

def on_left_mouse_hold ():

    if mode = sculpt
        mouse_pos = bpy.something.mouse_position
        mouse_speed = (mouse_pos - last_mouse_pos) ** 2
        bpy.something.sculpt.brush_strength = 1 / mousespeed
        last_mouse_pos = mouse_pos
```

Comment: How does this differ from your other question? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72917/simulate-pressure-sensitivity-with-mouse-speed

Comment: Sorry, I deleted another question, will be edited next time.